# Filter dataframe based on list with ranges

Tags: python, pandas

probably the title of my question is some kind of wrong. Currently I have a list:

```
a = [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,37,38,39]
```

and a dataframe df:

```
colfrom   colto
1          99
23         24
25         32
25         40
```

How can I filter my dataframe  that the `colfrom` is inside the array a or smaller then it, and that `colto`is inside the array or bigger then it? So basically this rule would lead to:

```
colfrom   colto
1          99
25         32
25         40
```

The only row who gets kicked out is row 2 (or in python row 1), as 23 and 24 are not in the array (and not lower then 11 and not higher then 39).

Comment: not its all values: [0,....,25,...,32]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
mask = ((df['colfrom'].isin(a)) | (df['colfrom']<min(a)) & (df['colto'].isin(a)) | (df['colto']>max(a)))
df[mask]

   colfrom  colto
0        1     99
2       25     32
3       25     40
```